# Convert java.lang.Boolean[][] to usable MATLAB array?

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I'm using MATLAB to access a postgresql database.  I'm running into problems trying to access a column of type `boolean[]`:

```
x;#% x is a <1x1 org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array>
```

When accessing `real[]` values, I can take the following approach:

```
double(x.getArray());
```

Unfortunately, with a `boolean[]` this leads to the following error message:

```
Undefined function 'toDouble' for input arguments of type 'logical'.
```

So I figured converting to `logical` first may work:

```
logical(x.getArray());
```

Except this doesn't work either.

```
Error using logical
Conversion to logical from java.lang.Boolean[][] is not possible.
```

The problem may arise because java.lang.Boolean doesn't derive from java.lang.Number, however [the MATLAB docs on conversion of java return types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f6671.html#bq__508-1) make it seem like this shouldn't be a problem.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get from the `fetch` result to a logical array usable in MATLAB? If all else fails, I can rebuild the tables with arrays of numeric types instead of `boolean[]`, but it seems like this should be possible without going that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is due to the difference in Java between `Boolean` (an object) and `boolean`, a primitive.  Matlab conversions are really set up to handle primitives, not necessarily their associated object wrappers.

I think that this conversion requires a loop, as follows:

```
%Setup test
b = java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
array = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(b.getClass(), [5 6]);
for ix1=1:length(array); 
    for ix2 = 1:(length(array(1))); 
        array(ix1, ix2)=b; 
    end; 
end;
%Now `array` is an initialize 2D Java array of type Boolean.

%To convert to a Matlab logical array
matArray = false(length(array), length(array(1)));  %Initialize
for ix1=1:size(matArray, 1); 
    for ix2 = 1:size(matArray, 2); 
        matArray(ix1, ix2)=(array(ix1, ix2).booleanValue());
        %The  `booleanValue()` method converts from `Boolean` class  to `boolean` primitive
    end; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me onto `booleanValue` - once I indexed all the way in to the array (so I wasn't just getting another array back out), that method became available.  Rather than looping, `arrayfun(@(x)x.booleanValue, array(:) )` (reshaped as needed) did the trick nicely.